# Is AC2 lumber ok to use with aluminum?

Tags: lumber, aluminum

My "local" big-box home improvement store sells a pressure treated lumber called AC2. Apparently this is different from ACQ in that its environmentally friendly, but still can be safely used with aluminum. I can't find very much online about this other than the product brochure from the manufacturer [here](https://www.midwestmanufacturing.com/MidwestManufacturing/web/docs/pdf/cms/AC2PressureTreated.pdf).

I'm just trying to get confirmation from someone unrelated to Menards that this lumber is ok to use with aluminum flashing because everything else says not to use aluminum with the new types of pressure treated lumber. Thanks.

Comment: First is that AC2 is a registered trademark for Menards and Midwest manufacturing.   In all of their literature for AC2 the AC2 part is actually CCA.  So this will help in your search for more info.  [THIS LINK](http://www.deckmagazine.com/products/materials-hardware/beyond-aluminum-flashing_o) shows alternatives and explores why aluminum should not be used.  The copper has a part in the reason in addition to the corrosive properties.  CCA/AC2 has copper.

Comment: I contacted Midwest Manufacturing and they told me to use this for flashing: https://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/siding/aluminum-siding/1-1-2-x-10-aluminum-deck-flashing/p-1444424176354-c-5825.htm?tid=-7352823444800701101

Comment: I guess my question now then is what should I put behind that and the ledger board then?